Is there any way to run multiple selenium webdrivers within a python script?
So I'm currently embarking on my web scraping/data analysis journey and was curious if there is anyway to have several selenium webdrivers running at the same time?
This script is for a mobile game called "Clash Royale". What I want to achieve is to have different player_tags running through the different selenium webdrivers at the same time to improve the efficiency of my script. Currently, it's taking about 20 seconds, on average, to scrape one players data. I couldn't quite understand how to get this running properly/smoothly, I've tried a few solutions like using Semaphore etc. however can't seem to get it running correctly. Some issues I ran into was it was only scraping a fraction of the overall amount of players, say there was like 24 players in a clan, it would only scrape like 8 players. I'm quite stuck and confused on this so decided to share a post here. Any help would be appreciated! Here are the scripts:
I'll just run you guys through the process of how these scripts intertwine with each other. The script aftermath_militia_scraper.py scrapes data from specific clan URLs, extracting player information and generating a detailed Excel spreadsheet with the data, including clan war statistics and player profiles, which are formatted and organized for easy viewing. It uses asynchronous requests to fetch data concurrently, processes the HTML content with BeautifulSoup, and utilizes openpyxl for Excel manipulation. The script imports and uses the scrape_clan_wars_info function from player_war_scraper.py, which gathers detailed war statistics for each player, including card levels, win percentages, and other metrics, by scraping RoyaleAPI using Selenium and httpx for web requests.
aftermath_militia_scraper.py:
import http.client
import urllib
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import re
import httpx
import logging
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Alignment, PatternFill, Border, Side
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from player_war_scraper import scrape_clan_wars_info  # Import the scrape_clan_wars_info function from player_war_scraper.py
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
import tqdm

# Set the logging level to suppress messages
logging.getLogger('urllib3').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)


# List of clan URLs with corresponding names
clan_urls = [
      ('https://statsroyale.com/clan/QY920UQR', 'Afterburn'),
    # Add more clan URLs as needed
]

# Define column widths
column_widths = {'A': 13, 'B': 25, 'C': 5, 'D': 8, 'E': 20, 'G': 13, 'H': 20}

# Create a new workbook
wb = Workbook()

async def fetch_clan_data(url, clan_name):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return clan_name, response.text
    
async def fetch_all_clan_data():
    tasks = [fetch_clan_data(url, clan_name) for url, clan_name in clan_urls]
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def generate_main_spreadsheet(clan_data):

    print("Generating Aftermath Militia Main Spreadsheet...")
    try:
        # Create a new workbook for the main spreadsheet
        main_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

        # Delete the default sheet
        main_wb.remove(main_wb.active)

        # Create a dictionary to store clan war stats
        clan_war_stats = {}

        for clan_name, content in clan_data:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

            # Find the divs containing headers and player rows
            headers_div = soup.find('div', class_='clan__headers')
            rows_divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='clan__rowContainer')

            # Extract header names
            headers = ['Player Tag', 'Name', 'Level', 'Trophies', 'Player Page']


            # Extract player data for Name, Level, Trophies, and Player Page

            players_data = []
            for row_div in rows_divs:
                player_data = [data.get_text(strip=True) for index, data in enumerate(row_div.find_all('div')) if index in [1, 2]]
                trophies = row_div.find('div', class_='clan__cup')
                player_data.append(trophies.get_text(strip=True) if trophies else '')  # If trophies exist, append them, otherwise append an empty string
                # Extract player tag from the profile link
                profile_link = row_div.find('a', class_='ui__blueLink')['href']
                player_tag = re.findall(r'[\w]+$', profile_link)[0]  # Extract player tag from the href link
                player_data.insert(0, player_tag)  # Insert player tag
                # Construct the royaleapi.com player page link
                player_page_link = f'https://royaleapi.com/player/{player_tag}'
                player_data.append(player_page_link)  # Append player page link
                
                # Replace emojis with spaces in the name using regular expression
                player_data[1] = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', player_data[1])
                
                players_data.append(player_data)


            # Create a new worksheet for the current clan with the clan name
            ws = main_wb.create_sheet(title=clan_name)

            # Write data to the worksheet

            ws.append(headers)
            for player in players_data:
                # Apply formatting to Player Page column
                player[-1] = f'=HYPERLINK("{player[-1]}", "View on RoyaleAPI")'
                
                # Write row to worksheet
                ws.append(player)


            # Apply bold formatting to headers

            for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1):
                for cell in row:
                    cell.font = Font(size=9)
                    cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')

            # Apply formatting to "View on RoyaleAPI" hyperlink text
            for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=5, max_col=5):
                for cell in row:
                    cell.font = Font(color='31869B', underline='single')

            # Merge Player Page header
            ws.merge_cells('E1:E1')
            ws['E1'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')

            # Adjust column widths
            column_widths = {'A': 14, 'B': 25, 'C': 8, 'D': 10, 'E': 40}  # Example widths
            for col, width in column_widths.items():
                ws.column_dimensions[col].width = width

            # Align all cells in column E to middle and center
            for cell in ws['E']:
                cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')

            # Align all cells in column C and D to middle and center
            for col in ['C', 'D']:
                for cell in ws[col]:
                    cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')

            # Apply alternating row fill colors
            for i, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=5), start=2):
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    fill_color = 'FFFFFF'  # White color
                else:
                    fill_color = 'D9D9D9'  # Light gray color
                for cell in row:
                    cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color=fill_color, end_color=fill_color, fill_type='solid')

            # Add borders to all cells with color #BFBFBF
            border = Border(left=Side(border_style='thin', color='BFBFBF'),
                            right=Side(border_style='thin', color='BFBFBF'),
                            top=Side(border_style='thin', color='BFBFBF'),
                            bottom=Side(border_style='thin', color='BFBFBF'))

            for row in ws.iter_rows():
                for cell in row:
                    cell.border = border

            # Display clan information
            members_count = len(players_data)
            last_updated = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y | %H:%M:%S")  # Corrected date and time format
            ws['G2'] = f'Clan: '
            ws['H2'] = f'{clan_name}'
            ws['G3'] = f'Members: '
            ws['H3'] = f'{members_count}'
            ws['G4'] = f'Last Updated: '
            ws['H4'] = f'{last_updated}'

            # Apply formatting to clan information
            info_cells = ['G2', 'H2', 'G3', 'H3', 'G4', 'H4']
            for cell in info_cells:
                ws[cell].font = Font(size=11)
                ws[cell].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='right', vertical='center')

            # Apply fill colors to clan information
            ws['G2'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFFFF', end_color='FFFFFF', fill_type='solid')  # White fill
            ws['H2'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFFFF', end_color='FFFFFF', fill_type='solid')  # White fill
            ws['G3'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='D9D9D9', end_color='D9D9D9', fill_type='solid')  # Light gray fill
            ws['H3'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='D9D9D9', end_color='D9D9D9', fill_type='solid')  # Light gray fill
            ws['G4'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFFFF', end_color='FFFFFF', fill_type='solid')  # White fill
            ws['H4'].fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFFFF', end_color='FFFFFF', fill_type='solid')  # White fill

            # Apply borders to clan information
            for cell in info_cells:
                ws[cell].border = border

            # Align text in Column G to the right and text in Column H to the left within the clan information
            for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=4, min_col=7, max_col=8):
                for cell in row:
                    if cell.column == 7:  # Column G
                        cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='right', vertical='center')
                    else:  # Column H
                        cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center')

            # Store player data for clan in a dictionary
            clan_war_stats[clan_name] = players_data

        # Generate clan war stats asynchronously
        await generate_clan_war_stats(clan_war_stats, main_wb)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        # Save the main spreadsheet
        main_wb.save("Aftermath_Militia_All_Data.xlsx")

async def generate_clan_war_stats(clan_data, main_wb):
    try:
        print(f"Type of clan_data: {type(clan_data)}")  # Add this line to check the type of clan_data

        for clan_name, players_data in clan_data.items():
            print(f"Processing war stats for clan {clan_name}...")

            # Create a new workbook for the clan's war stats
            clan_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

            for idx, player_data in enumerate(tqdm.tqdm(players_data, desc=f'Clan: {clan_name}'), start=1):
                player_tag = player_data[0]
                print(f"Gathering war information for {player_tag} | #{idx}...")

                # Skip invalid player tags
                if not re.match(r'^#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$', player_tag):
                    print(f"Invalid player tag '{player_tag}', skipping...")
                    continue

                try:
                    war_stats = await scrape_clan_wars_info(player_tag)  # Scrape war stats for the player
                    if war_stats:
                        player_war_stats = war_stats[0]['War Statistics']  # Extract war stats for the player

                        # Create a new worksheet for the player within the clan's workbook
                        ws = clan_wb.create_sheet(title=player_tag)

                        # Write player's war stats to the worksheet
                        ws.append(['You', 'Opp', 'Season ID', 'Date', 'Clan Name', 'Decks Used', 'Fame'])  # Write headers
                        for stat in player_war_stats:
                            row = list(stat.values())
                            ws.append(row)

                        print(f"War information for {player_tag} gathered successfully.")
                    else:
                        print(f"No war information found for {player_tag}.")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"An error occurred while gathering war information for {player_tag}: {str(e)}")

            # Save the clan's war stats to a single file after processing all players
            clan_stats_filename = f"{clan_name}_war_stats.xlsx"
            clan_wb.save(clan_stats_filename)

            print(f"War stats for clan {clan_name} generated successfully.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while generating war stats: {str(e)}")
        
async def main():
    try:
        clan_data = await fetch_all_clan_data()
        await generate_main_spreadsheet(clan_data)
        await generate_clan_war_stats(clan_data, main_wb=None)

        print("Script completed successfully.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

player_war_scraper.py:
import re
import sys
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import httpx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import StringIO

# Placeholder value for the number of rows of information to generate
num_rows = 12

async def scrape_clan_wars_info(player_tag):
    try:
        # Scrape card levels
        card_levels_df = await scrape_card_levels(player_tag)

        # Scrape war stats
        war_stats_df = await scrape_war_stats(player_tag)
        
        # Scrape win percentage
        win_stats = await scrape_win_percentage(player_tag)

        if win_stats:
            win_percentage = win_stats.get("Percentage")
            wins = win_stats.get("Wins")
            count = win_stats.get("Count")
        else:
            win_percentage = None
            wins = None
            count = None

        # Merge card levels and war stats into one DataFrame
        combined_df = pd.concat([card_levels_df, war_stats_df], axis=1)

        # Add win statistics columns
        combined_df['Wins'] = wins
        combined_df['Count'] = count
        combined_df['Percentage'] = win_percentage

        # Convert the DataFrame to a list of dictionaries
        combined_data = combined_df.to_dict(orient='records')

        return [{'War Statistics': combined_data}]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while scraping war information for player {player_tag}: {str(e)}")
        return []

async def scrape_card_levels(player_tag):
    urls = [
        f"https://royaleapi.com/player/{player_tag}/battles/history?battle_type=warAny",
        f"https://royaleapi.com/player/{player_tag}/battles/history?before=1716772359000&&battle_type=warAny"
    ]

    all_data = []
    unique_battles = set()  # To keep track of unique battles

    for idx, url in enumerate(urls):
        data = await scrape_data(url)
        for battle_data in data:
            if tuple(battle_data['You']) not in unique_battles:  # Check if battle data already seen
                all_data.append(battle_data)
                unique_battles.add(tuple(battle_data['You']))  # Add battle data to the set of unique battles
        if idx < len(urls) - 1:  # Add an empty row between data from each URL
            all_data.append({})

    # Combine all battles into one DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['You', 'Opp'])
    for battle_data in all_data:
        if not battle_data:  # If empty row, skip
            continue
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(battle_data)
        df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], ignore_index=True)

    # Convert 'You' and 'Opp' columns to numeric
    df['You'] = df['You'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
    df['Opp'] = df['Opp'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

    return df

async def scrape_data(url):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
    }
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        all_battles = []
        segments_seen = set()  # To keep track of segments already seen

        for battle in soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile(r'\bbattle_\w+')):
            segments = battle.find_all('div', class_='ui basic segment team-segment')
            segment_ids = tuple(id(seg) for seg in segments)  # Get unique IDs for segments

            if segment_ids not in segments_seen:  # Check if segments already seen
                you_cards = []
                opp_cards = []

                for i, segment in enumerate(segments):
                    card_levels = segment.find_all('div', class_='ui basic center card-level')
                    if i % 2 == 0:  # Player's segment
                        # Extract only the numbers from card levels and convert to integers
                        you_cards.extend([int(re.search(r'\d+', card.get_text()).group()) for card in card_levels])
                    else:  # Opponent's segment
                        # Extract only the numbers from card levels and convert to integers
                        opp_cards.extend([int(re.search(r'\d+', card.get_text()).group()) for card in card_levels])

                # Ensure the length of the lists is the same
                max_length = max(len(you_cards), len(opp_cards))
                you_cards.extend([None] * (max_length - len(you_cards)))
                opp_cards.extend([None] * (max_length - len(opp_cards)))

                all_battles.append({'You': you_cards, 'Opp': opp_cards})
                segments_seen.add(segment_ids)  # Add segment IDs to the set

        return all_battles

async def scrape_war_stats(player_tag):
    war_stats = []
    url = f"https://royaleapi.com/player/{player_tag}"
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    # Configure Chrome options for headless mode and disable image loading
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # Disable GPU acceleration
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")  # Disable info bars
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Disable /dev/shm usage
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Disable sandbox mode
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")  # Disable extensions
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")  # Disable browser side navigation
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor")  # Disable viz display compositor
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  # Start maximized
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2})  # Disable image loading
    chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    # Suppress logging to the console

    # Initialize Chrome WebDriver with configured options
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    load_time = 1200

    # Set implicit wait time
    driver.implicitly_wait(load_time)

    # Open the webpage
    driver.get(url)

    try:

        accept_cookies(driver)

        # Click the button to load war history
        load_war_history(driver)

        # Wait for the table to be loaded
        table = WebDriverWait(driver, load_time).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "player__cw2_history_table")))

        # Get the table headers with their respective data content
        headers = [th.get_attribute("data-content") for th in table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "th")]

        # Specify the columns to select
        selected_columns = ['Season ID', 'Date', 'Clan Name', 'Decks Used', 'Fame']

        # Get the table data
        table_html = table.get_attribute('outerHTML')

        # Read the HTML into a DataFrame
        df = pd.read_html(StringIO(table_html))[0]

        # Rename the columns with their respective data content
        df.columns = headers

        # Select only the specified columns
        df_selected_columns = df[selected_columns]

        # Select only the specified number of rows
        df_selected_rows = df_selected_columns.head(num_rows)

        # Convert the DataFrame to a dictionary
        player_war_stats = df_selected_rows.to_dict(orient='records')

        # Create a dictionary to hold all war stats for the player
        consolidated_stats = {'Player Tag': player_tag, 'War Statistics': player_war_stats}

        # Append consolidated stats to the war_stats list
        war_stats.append(consolidated_stats)

    finally:
        # Close the WebDriver
        driver.quit()

    return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(stats['War Statistics']) for stats in war_stats])

async def scrape_win_percentage(player_tag):
    url = f"https://royaleapi.com/player/{player_tag}"
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
    }
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        # Initialize variables to store win statistics
        win_percentage = None
        wins = None
        count = None

        # Find all tables in the page
        tables = soup.find_all('table')

        # Look for the table containing "Percentage" and "Count"
        for table in tables:
            if "Percentage" in table.get_text() and "Count" in table.get_text():
                # Find the tbody element within the table
                tbody = table.find('tbody')
                # Extract the first row (index 0) from tbody
                if tbody:
                    first_row = tbody.find('tr')
                    # Extract text content from the first row
                    if first_row:
                        cells = first_row.find_all('td')
                        if len(cells) >= 3:
                            wins = cells[0].text.strip()
                            count = cells[1].text.strip()
                            win_percentage = cells[2].text.strip()
                        break
        
        # Check if all required stats were found
        if win_percentage is not None and wins is not None and count is not None:
            return {
                "Wins": f"Wins: {wins}, Count: {count}, Percentage: {win_percentage}",
            }
        else:
            print("Percentage and Count table not found.")
            return None

def accept_cookies(driver):
    try:
        # Switch to the iframe
        driver.switch_to.frame("sp_message_iframe_1117080")

        # Switch to the document within the iframe
        iframe_document = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "html")
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_document)

        # Locate the "Accept" button within the dropdown
        accept_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Accept')]")

        # Click the "Accept" button
        accept_button.click()

        # Switch back to the default content
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
    except:
        pass  # No cookie prompt found, continue without accepting

def load_war_history(driver):
    # Click the button using JavaScript
    load_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "cw2_history_button")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", load_button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Please provide the player tag:")
        sys.exit(1)

    player_tag = sys.argv[1]
    asyncio.run(scrape_clan_wars_info(player_tag))

